# Boot screen error (?)

Tags: boot

I get to the login screen, put in my password, press enter then a black screen with a flashing  line appears for 3 seconds then it goes back to the login screen

Answer (score -1):

is an internal error, probably a erase of a file in the system, try to reinstall